# Stanford-CoreNLP: requests.exceptions.HTTPError when parsing long sentences

Tags: stanford-nlp

I use CoreNLPParser to parsing Chinese text sentence by sentence but got **requests.exceptions.HTTPError**. when meet long sentences.

I notice that the official documentation said: long sentences blow out processing time and memory. Is this why the requests.exceptions.HTTPError raise?

What should I do when I want to parsing these long sentences?

my code is:

```py
from nltk.parse import CoreNLPParser
parser = CoreNLPParser('http://localhost:9001')
for seg_sent in sentences:
    tree = parser.raw_parse(seg_sent)
```

when the sentence is long, like:

> 例如 ， 从 一 棵 大 柳树 上 剪 下 几 根 枝条 插 进 土 里 ， 枝条 就 会 长成 一株株 活泼 可爱 的 小 柳树 ； 把 马铃薯 切 成 许多 小 块 种 进 地 里 ， 就 能 收获 许多 新鲜 的 马铃薯 ； 把 仙人掌 切 成 几 块 ， 每块 落地 不久 就 会 生根 ， 长成 新 的 仙人掌 …… 此外 ， 一些 植物 还 可以 通过 压条 或 嫁接 培育 后代 。

or

> 为了 人类 能够 生活 在 一个 “ 和而不同 ” 的 世界 上 ， 从 现在 起 就 必须 提倡 在 审美 的 、 人文 的 层次 上 ， 在 人们 的 社会活动 中 树立 起 一个 “ 美美与共 ” 的 文化 心态 ， 这 是 人们 思想 观念 上 的 一 场 深刻 大 变革 ， 它 可能 与 当前 世界 上 很多 人 习惯 的 思维 模式 和 行为 方式 相 抵触 。

the error will raise:

```py
File "Parser.py", line 222, in BuildTree
tree = parser.raw_parse(seg_sent)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/nltk/parse/corenlp.py", line 229, in raw_parse
[sentence], properties=default_properties, *args, **kwargs
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/nltk/parse/corenlp.py", line 284, in raw_parse_sents
parsed_data = self.api_call('\n'.join(sentences), properties=default_properties)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/nltk/parse/corenlp.py", line 250, in api_call
response.raise_for_status()
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/models.py", line 840, in raise_for_status
raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 500 Server Error: Internal Server Error for url: http://localhost:9001/?properties=%7B%22annotators%22%3A+%22tokenize%2Cpo2Clemma%2Cssplit%2Cparse%22%2C+%22ssplit.ssplit.eolonly%22%3A+%22true%22%2C+%22outputFormat%22%3A+%22json%22%2C+%22tokenize.whitespace%22%3A+%22false%22%
```

I am a new to programming, so please explain the reason in a simpler way. I will very appreciate for your reply. Thank you~